# Validação no model ao fazer update_attributes no Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quero saber como faria uma validação no meu model para quando o @model.update_attributes(params) no meu controller for chamado retornar um possível erro ou false que parece ser o padrão retornado pelo update_attributes.

Seguindo a lógica de fat models, pensei em colocar a validação no model pois emagreceria meu controller.

A dúvida é como implementar isso no model para que meu controller continue apenas com @model.update_attributes(params). E retorne false caso a validação não passe.

A validação deve acontecer apenas no update.

Comment: Tentei isso
   validate :tem_no_estoque, :before => :update

porém o objeto ainda é salvo mesmo adicionando um erro e retornando falso no método tem_no_estoque.
Até sem o :before => :update o objeto ainda é salvo. 

Só para contextualizar, estou tentando evitar o update de um line_item do spree caso este line_item não tenha o produto em estoque. O estoque neste caso não usa o default do spree e sim uma customização.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassio, considerando que você quer fazer essa validação apenas no update, você poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :active_customer, on: :update

  def active_customer
    errors.add(:customer_id, "is not active") unless customer.active?
  end
end
```

Você pode ver a documentação disso, aqui: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: Essa realmente é a solução. Acabei chegando a ela pelo guia. Mas não consegui resolver o meu problema. No meu caso eu tenho um model Order que possui vários LineItem e os line items são atualizados pelo Order#update o que de algum modo fez com que essa validação do LineItem não funcionasse.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode implemantar o [Active Record Validations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Exemplo:

Você tem um model chamado User com os atributos `:name`, `:email`, `:password`, nele você pode adicionar as validações:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 5 }
    validates :email, presence: true
end
```

E ai no seu método update você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
def
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
            format.html # index.html.erb
        else
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

O `@user.errors` iré exibir os erros do validade.

Espero que ajude :)

Comment: Opa @seujota, eu editei a pergunta. Preciso que a validação aconteça apenas ao fazer o update no model. Porquê dentre todas as validações quero que essa validação impeça o update pois é crítica.

Comment: @CassioCabral você pode manter esse mesmo formato que eu propus, aí no momento que você não quiser usar a validação vc pode "pulá-la" `@user.save(:validate => false)` se ainda quiser outras alternativas vc pode criar métodos de validação no model e usar um callback como o `after_update` por exemplo.

Comment: Não funciona. Eu preciso de algo específico, uma verificação em todo update. Pois checo se um valor mudou, caso tenha mudado verifico se ele pode ser modificado segundo a lógica da aplicação. Caso verdade ele prossegue com a atualização normalmente. Algo no caminho de um custom method(http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) mas que valide apenas ao realizar o update. A questão de passar o validate não convém e no caso seria ideal um before_validate chame um custom_method. Este model é um line_item, ele só é salvo após ter sido atualizado, é a regra.